# SA login can't create database in Docker container

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I have a Docker project that uses MSSQL to store some databases. I recently decided to delete and recreate the containers to purge some broken info, but I'm having some issues getting the DBs set up again.

I have a Python script that's meant to automatically create the databases - it logs in using the `sa` account and then executes a bunch of .sql files to create and setup everything. In the past, this has worked completely fine to get everything set up the first time I start up the containers. However, I'm now getting an error that's suggesting the `sa` account somehow doesn't have permission to create a database.

When the Python script starts running, it successfully logs in using the following connection string: `DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};SERVER=<server_address>;DATABASE=master;UID=sa;PWD=<password>;ENCRYPT=no`. It also successfully runs the first of the .sql files, which creates a non-admin login (`CREATE LOGIN cbs_user WITH PASSWORD = '******'`) for future users to make use of.

However, once it starts running the next .sql file, which creates and then sets up a database called Facebook, it fails. My terminal displays the following:

```
2023-10-27 15:32:16.40 spid51 Failed to get the volume information, -1073741772
2023-10-27 15:32:16.41 spid51 Failed to get the volume information, -1073741772
2023-10-27 15:32:16.41 spid51 CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file '/opt/mssql/data/Facebook.mdf'.
```

After that, the rest of my project setup fails because it tries to access that database, or one of a few others in my project, none of which were successfully created. Any idea how I can fix this? The error message suggests that the login trying to create the database doesn't have permission to do so, but shouldn't `sa` have all permissions by default?

Comment: That to me looks more like the file doesn't exist where the script expects it to be, or that the permissions on the file are restricted such that SQL can't access it. I'd verify the mdf file exists at that path, and check the permissions on it.

Comment: The problem isn't the `sa` `LOGIN` the problem is *outside* the instance and at the file system level. The directory you are trying to write to doesn't allow the `mssql` user or group to read and write to it.

Comment: SQL Server for Linux (and Docker) don't create database files in `/opt/mssql/data` by default (that directory doesn't exist in official images). Are you specifying file paths in your `CREATE DATABASE` commands? Have you tried using the default directory `/var/opt/mssql/data` instead?

Comment: Aside... the `sa` account doesn't have any special permissions outside of the SQL Server process. When using the official `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` images the SQL Server process executes in the context of a least-privileged user, `mssql`, so only has limited permissions inside the container's file system.

Comment: The CREATE DATABASE commands do indeed specify file paths, but they've been written that way ever since I started using this script, and there were no issues like this in the past. The permissions on the /opt folder were `dwrxr-xr-x`, and I tried manually changing them to `dwrxrwxrwx`, but that doesn't seem to have helped. What could have caused the user to no longer have the file permissions that it had before?